# How do you change source location of iframes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How do you change source location of iframes in JavaScript?

For example, but the click of a button or a link, change this:

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

...into this:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
```

And, if you want to do one better, how do I change multiple iframes within the same page (using `name` or some other identifier)?

Comment: This won't work, stack overflow uses frame busting and can't be framed (at least not easily) :-) .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, assign you iframe an id. This would look like

```
<iframe id="youridname" src=""></iframe>;.
```

Then your JavaScript command would  be

```
document.getElementById("youridname").src = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I assume you answered first so I'm accepting yours as the answer. They all show "answered 9 hours ago" so I picked the top one, which is yours.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than modifying any other tag.  Get the element, and set the property:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

And you can select against any attributes you like.  For example, if you have `<iframe data-id='some-frame' src='http://stackoverflow.com'></iframe>`, then you could select against either attribute:

```
var soFrames = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[src*='overflow']");
if (soFrames.length > 0) {
    soFrames[0].src = "something.com";
}
```

Or:

```
var soFrames = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[data-id='some-frame']")
```

<sub>(Note that there are security restrictions, so you can't just display any random website like Stackoverflow.com in your page's iframe.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the frames in a page from `window.frames`.  This contains a collection of the frames' `window` objects.  From there you modify the `location.href` of the frame's `window`:

```
frames[0].location.href = "page1.htm";
frames[1].location.href = "page2.htm";
```

You can also get at a frame's window by referencing the frame element's `contentWindow` property:

```
document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow.location.href = "page1.htm";
```

To go backwards, that is, get the frame *element* from it's window, use the `frameElement` property:

```
frames[0].frameElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```